# Get sum of array till number

Tags: php, arrays

Now I have an array which keeps varying but is like this:-

```
  Array ( [0] => 10000.00000000 [1] => 10001.00000000 [2] => 1000.00000000 )
```

I have an amount lets say

```
 10020.00000000
```

How do I loop this array such that it stops when it finds that the amount sum is reached and it cannot take more value. Like the array should loop till [1] and record the value as [0] + [1] are only required as subtracting value from [0] leaves us with 0 and [1] leaves with 9981. Thus third value is not required as second is still not 0. Thanks for understanding

Comment: Have you tried a simple `foreach()` loop?

Comment: But I dont know how to stop it once it reaches the value

Comment: `break;` will exit a loop https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: How do I know when the sum inside the array reaches the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through all the elements using `foreach` and summing then, also checking whenever the sum is equal to the value you want, then using `break` to exit the loop:

```php
$arr = array(10000.00000000, 10001.00000000, 1000.00000000);
$sum = 0;
foreach($arr as $num)
{
    $sum += $num;
    if($sum >= 10020.00000000) break;

}
```

Comment: How do I echo the number of values out?

Comment: For each iteration? just echo `$num` which is the current number in each iteration

Comment: It's best to compare with an inequality. With floats, there's a good chance `$sum` will never exactly equal the target value, so the loop will continue past it.

Comment: @DaCurse I want to echo out the number of objects in the array that were there before the break

Comment: @DaCurse like it should be 2 in this case

Comment: @ZoooccRefback you can include the index in the foreach loop definition. The count after the break will be the current index + 1.

Comment: Use `>` instead of  `==`, else this will be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the if statement. @ZoooccRefback, the loop will stop once break is called, if you echo out `$num` inside the loop, it will echo out all of the numbers until the break is called, so all of the numbers that form the sum.